# Editor Templates at Runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generics, model-binding, mvc-editor-templates

This problem is a little hard to explain so I'll try to give an example. Say I have the following type:

```
public class FieldResult<T> {
    public Field Field { get; set; }
    public T Answer { get; set; }

    public FieldResult(Field field) {
        Field = field;
    }
}
```

Now say I have the following view model:

```
public class Form {
    public IList<FieldResult<object>> Results { get; set; }

    public Form(IList<Field> fields) {
        Results = fields.Select(f => new FieldResult<object>(f)).ToList();
    }
}
```

If I say the following in the view:

```
@foreach (var result in Model.Results) {
    @Html.EditorFor(m => result, "CheckBoxField")
}
```

Now say I have the following CheckBoxField editor template:

```
@model FieldResult<bool>
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Answer)
```

It all compiles fine but I get the following error at runtime:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'FieldResult`1[System.Object]', but this dictionary requires a model
>   item of type 'FieldResult`1[System.Boolean]'.

I'd appreciate it if someone could say whether this is possible and possibly suggest a way of going about it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to pass a `FieldResult<object>` value in a template whose model is of type `FieldResult<bool>`, they're different types so you get that error. You can either change your `Results` property and make it an `IList<FieldResult<bool>>`, or cast your collection items in your view.

If you need to build different types of results, you can also consider using class inheritance :

```
public abstract class FieldResult {
    public Field Field { get; set; }

    public FieldResult(Field field) {
        Field = field;
    }
}

public class BooleanFieldResult : FieldResult {
    public bool Answer { get; set; }

    public FieldResult(Field field) : base(field) {
    }
}
```

Your `Form` class would look like this :

```
public class Form {
    public IList<FieldResult> Results { get; set; }

    public Form(IList<Field> fields) {
        Results = // ... you choose which child class inherited from FieldResult you want to use
    }
}
```

Your view would check which type it is :

```
@foreach (var result in Model.Results) {
    if(result is BooleanFieldResult) {
        var booleanResult = (BooleanFieldResult)result;
        @Html.EditorFor(m => booleanResult , "CheckBoxField")
    }
}
```

Then your `CheckBoxField` template would look like this :

```
@model BooleanFieldResult
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Answer)
```

Comment: Thanks this gave the error "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions." so I took the cast outside of the editor for and stored it in a variable and it displayed correctly. I'll leave this open for now as I need to do abit more work but thanks for putting me in the right direction.

Comment: I've just finished my testing and this is working nicely. I was able to get rid of a lot of rubbish code I had and this approach allows me to do custom validation for each of the field types. Thanks again.